# Point Estimation of the Proportion

Tags: self-study

A survey of 170 randomly selected undergraduate students show that 119 prefer to study in their room.

What is the point estimation of the proportion of students who prefer to study in their room?

Would it just be 119/170 = 70%

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have n=179 Bernoulli trials, so if you use the MLE,

Likelihood= $\prod{p^{x_{i}}{(1-p)}^{1-x_{i}}}=p^{\sum{x_{i}}}(1-p)^{n-\sum{x_{i}}}$

$Loglik=log(p)\sum{x_{i}}+log(1-p)(n-\sum{x_{i}})$

The you can Find the derivative
, make it equal to zero and solve it. Your estimator Will be
$\hat{p}=\bar{X}=\frac{119}{179}$